# What function can produce a perfect saddleback plot and fulfil the following requirement?

Tags: functions, 3d

I need to find a function that produce a good saddleback plot.

The function has the following requirements:

1. Having 2 arguments: x and y
2. Both x and y are natural numbers
3. The result of the function is natural number
4. The function is increasing in each argument

In order to plot a saddleback (in 3D), I tried $ x^2 - y^2 $, which gives such [plot](https://www.google.co.uk/search?es_sm=91&q=x%5E2-y%5E2&oq=x%5E2-y%5E2&gs_l=serp.3..35i39j0l9.46197.48865.0.49101.7.7.0.0.0.0.69.352.7.7.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..0.7.350.FLfWyppR9WE):

[image]

It looks like a saddleback, but **it doesn't fit to the requirements**.

I then tried $ 3x+27y+y^2 $, it gives [plot](https://www.google.co.uk/search?es_sm=91&q=3x%2B27y%2By%5E2&oq=3x%2B27y%2By%5E2&gs_l=serp.3..35i39.584872.584872.0.585048.1.1.0.0.0.0.47.47.1.1.0.msedr...0...1c.2.64.serp..0.1.47.rWGk3fy-Wwc) like this:

[image]

It is not that *saddleback*, right?

So can anyone supply me a good one on this?

Comment: This is a parabolic cylinder.

Comment: @Bernard what is a saddleback then?

Comment: I know what is a *saddle surface* (as a function of real variables, which is the first plot  you show, and is called, mathematically a, *hyperbolic paraboloid*. However it  never can be increasing in each variable, as all non-degenerate quadrics.

Comment: @Bernard could you help me produce a function fitting to all the requirements in my question?

Comment: You can take the function $f(x,y)=x*y$. If fulfills your requirements, and has the shape of a saddle, because after a linear coordinates change, it has an equation of type $Z=\dfrac{X^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{Y^2}{b^2}$.

Comment: @Bernard nice, could you please convert your comment to an answer? then I will mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What function can produce a perfect saddle  shape?

I propose  function $f(x,y)=x y $. It fulfills all the arithmetic conditions, and its plot has the shape of a saddle (‘hyperbolic paraboloid’) because, as a quadratic form it has signature (1,1), i.e. is the sum of a definite positive and a definite negative form:

$$ xy=\frac14(x+y)^2-\frac14(x-y)^2. $$

So it may be the same or some rotated shape.

Please suggest any equations to other such saddle shapes.

[image: Hypar 3D graph]